# Terraform variable validation Terraform v0.13 with length & Substr

Tags: validation, variables, terraform

**Terraform variable validation using length function**
Getting error while using length function & substr for vswitch_ids
Condition - vswitch_name value must start with vsw-

```
variable "vswitch_ids" {
description = "The vswitch IDs."
type        = list(string)
validation {
condition = (
  length(var.vswitch_ids) > 0 &&
  substr(var.switch_ids, 0, 4) == "vsw-" 
  )
error_message = "The vswitch_name value must start with \"vsw-\"."
```

}
}

```
Error: Invalid function argument 
on modules/k8s/variables.tf line 34, in variable "vswitch_ids":
34:       substr(var.vswitch_ids, 0, 4) == "vsw-" 
|----------------
| var.vswitch_ids is list of string with 3 elements
Invalid value for "str" parameter: string required.
```

Comment: The error is correct. `var.vswitch_ids` is list, not string. What do you want to achieve? Your use of `substr` does not make sense in your context.

Comment: what is the correct way of doing it?

Comment: Doing what? You haven't explained what do you want to do.

Comment: vswitch_name value must start with vsw- , need to do this with not using regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work. It will check if all elements in your variable list start with `vsw`:

```
variable "vswitch_ids" {
  description = "The vswitch IDs."
  type        = list(string)
  validation {
    condition = (
      length(var.vswitch_ids) > 0 &&
      length([for v in var.vswitch_ids: 1 if substr(v, 0, 4) == "vsw-"]) == length(var.vswitch_ids)
      )
      error_message = "The vswitch_name value must start with \"vsw-\"."
  }
}
```